# How to force counter starts from 01 instead of 1 (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, counter

I have 24 gif files and when i want to program Next button by a counter it starts from gif number 11 which i want to be from 01, so literally it skips first 10 gifs!

```
var counter = 0
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
    image.image = UIImage (named: "frame_\(counter)_delay-0.06s.gif")
    counter += 1
    if counter == 24 {
        counter = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: count the number with Int, and use formatted string to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, `String(format: "frame_%02d_delay-0.06s.gif",counter)`

so you will have following code,

```
let imageName = String(format: "frame_%02d_delay-0.06s.gif",counter)
image.image = UIImage (named: imageName)
```

Comment: Thanks, it just WORKS!